# How to send Token (not Ether) through a contract?

Tags: ether, tokens

I know `sendRawTransaction` can send Ether to another account address. Now, I need to use `sendRawTransaction` to send Token to another account address. In `sendRawTransaction`, the param `to` should be the contract's address, but  I don't know how to populate the param `data` nor how to tell the contract  the target account address. Who can tell me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working in the web3 console of, e.g. geth?

You need to first [create an instance of that contract](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract):

```
var contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
```

Now you can call the `transfer` function to send a defined `amount` of token from you account (e.g. account number 0) to the `recipient` account:

```
contractInstance.transfer(recipient, amount, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 200000});
```

Make sure to send enough gas, the exact value depends on the token.

Comment: i  use  the  web3js  libhttps://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/README.rst in Android  client  ，not the js function

Comment: i know  you  means  should  use  the  contract instance to call the transfer  custom  function  in  contract   replace  the sendrawtransaction function ?

Comment: Use `contractInstance.transfer` instead of `sendrawtransaction` if you can.